# What is the most cost effective way of installing a blue light free secondary lighting system for night use?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, lamp

I want to improve my sleep, and one thing that could help would be to reduce blue light as much as possible from 9pm onwards. Currently, I have 2700k overhead LED bulbs but that's still a bit bright. I am a renter so I can't make big modifications to the current lighting system or do much drilling.

My ideas so far:

- Installing dimmable red/yellow faerie lights in the bedroom and corridor
- Wearing a portable red/yellow lamp on my person and keeping the lights off (such as a neck reading lamp)

Comment: Why wear a lamp of any color to sleep?

Comment: @SolarMike I sleep in complete darkness, without any lamp. This would be for the evening period before going to sleep, and perhaps for waking up in the middle of the night as well.

Comment: While there is no great harm in changing a few light bulbs, I would consult a sleep specialist in a hospital-based sleep center before putting much more time or energy into eliminating light that is already fairly warm in color before bed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get programmable light bulbs, such as Philips HUE.   That is perfect for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of bulbs available with 2200K color temperature which is a nice warm "candlelight" color.

Another option would be remote-control variable color temperature bulbs. Most stop most at 2700K, but some will go down to 2200K (for example IKEA TRADFRI).

Answer (score 1):

The wearable or portable (& hopefully rechargeable) lamp is most cost effective *if* you can tolerate the annoyance of carrying your light source with you, since you only need the one.

In a less-renter-centric situation, color-changing LED light strips would be an obvious choice for a non-carry solution, but those might be a bit too difficult to demount cleanly when moving out.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave the apartment lighting unchanged and wear blue light blocking glasses after 9 PM. If you already wear prescription glasses, you can get blue light blocking clip-on shades.